# Frame rate drops when displaying google nestcam video using flutter_webrtc on android device

Tags: flutter, dart

Although nestcam has a frame rate of 30 fps, the frame rate of the video displayed on the android screen drops to 0.5 fps. How can I improve the frame rate on android?

There is no problem with network and machine power.

Below is the code for flutter's video display.
”_remoteRenderer” contains the mediastream obtained from nestcam according to the official procedure.

```
RTCVideoView(
 _remoteRenderer,
 mirror: false,
 objectFit: RTCVideoViewObjectFit.RTCVideoViewObjectFitCover,
),
```

Here is a log excerpt from flutter_webrtc that includes performance-related content.

```
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: initPlayout(sampleRate=48000, channels=1, bufferSizeFactor=1.0)
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: minBufferSizeInBytes: 7688
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: createAudioTrackBeforeOreo
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: nativeOutputSampleRate: 48000
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: session ID: 553, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000, max gain: 1.0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: buffer size in frames: 3844
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrack: buffer capacity in frames: 3844
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): VolumeLogger: start@[name=worker_thread - 1913, id=49]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): VolumeLogger: audio mode is: MODE_NORMAL
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: startPlayout
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=84]
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): WebRtcAudioTrackExternal: doAudioTrackStateCallback: 0
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): VolumeLogger: VOICE_CALL stream volume: 8 (max=8)
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): onAddTrack
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): onAddTrack
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): onConnectionChangeCONNECTING
W/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): FlutterRTCVideoRenderer.setVideoTrack, set video track to 9308e6dc-fc46-4916-beb1-e913ae3d61c1
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: Releasing.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: eglBase detach and release.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: Releasing done.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: Quitting render thread.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: Initializing EglRenderer
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: EglBase.create shared context
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
[log] received stream: Instance of 'MediaStreamNative'
[log] received stream: Instance of 'MediaStreamNative'
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): onSelectedCandidatePairChanged
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): onIceGatheringChangeCOMPLETE
D/FlutterWebRTCPlugin( 1726): onConnectionChangeCONNECTED
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: Duration: 4003 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: .0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): AndroidVideoDecoder: ctor name: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc type: H264 color format: 19 context: org.webrtc.EglBase14Impl$Context@99e8b53
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): AndroidVideoDecoder: ctor name: c2.android.avc.decoder type: H264 color format: 19 context: org.webrtc.EglBase14Impl$Context@99e8b53
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglBase14Impl: Using OpenGL ES version 2
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): AndroidVideoDecoder: initDecodeInternal name: OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc type: H264 width: 1920 height: 1080
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): SurfaceTextureHelper: Setting listener to org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder@b267fd
I/OMXClient( 1726): IOmx service obtained
D/MediaCodec( 1726): flushMediametrics
D/SurfaceUtils( 1726): connecting to surface 0x7d3c746d70, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec( 1726): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 1767426
D/SurfaceUtils( 1726): disconnecting from surface 0x7d3c746d70, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils( 1726): connecting to surface 0x7d3c746d70, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
W/ExtendedACodec( 1726): failed to reallocate omx vpp component: -2
I/ExtendedACodec( 1726): setupVideoDecoder()
I/ExtendedACodec( 1726): Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
W/ExtendedACodec( 1726): Failed to set frame packing format on component
D/SurfaceUtils( 1726): set up nativeWindow 0x7d3c746d70 for 1920x1080, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20402900
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): AndroidVideoDecoder: initDecodeInternal done
D/SurfaceUtils( 1726): set up nativeWindow 0x7d3c746d70 for 1920x1088, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20402900
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): AndroidVideoDecoder: Decoder format changed: {crop-right=1919, color-format=2141391878, slice-height=1088, mime=video/raw, hdr-static-info=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=25 cap=25], stride=1920, color-standard=1, color-transfer=3, crop-bottom=1079, crop-left=0, width=1920, color-range=2, crop-top=0, height=1088}
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): AndroidVideoDecoder: Frame stride and slice height: 1920 x 1088
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): CameraStatistics: Camera fps: 30.
I/org.webrtc.Logging( 1726): EglRenderer: Duration: 4003 ms. Frames received: 2. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 2. Render fps: .5. Average render time: 3931 us. Average swapBuffer time: 878 us.
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late but I had the same issue like you.

I've managed to find the culprit which is the pre-built source code of webrtc that is used inside the `flutter_webrtc` lib.

tldr: Use [getStream webrtc android source](https://github.com/GetStream/webrtc-android) or build webrtc sources by yourself (unfortunately for IOS you will probably built it anyway ). Fork the flutter_webrtc lib, replace dependency for ios and android ( this will require a little bit of code cleaning, as the webrtc source that is built by them has some additional features added like FrameCryptor) and it should work like a charm (stable 20-30fps from 0.5 before).

Unfortunately I did not analyse how the flutter_webrtc team is building the sources and why they are not working with google nest cameras.

Steps to fix the android version and check it by yourself:

1. Fork flutter_webrtc and open android/build.gradle file
2. Replace `implementation 'io.github.webrtc-sdk:android:114.5735.08.1'` with `implementation 'io.getstream:stream-webrtc-android:1.1.1'` ( we can use getstream version of the sources which should be working )
3. Get rid of the `FlutterRTCFrameCryptor.java` ( maybe a few more files that would prevent building, you can also go to the `flutter_webrtc` repo and copy those classes to the fork but I didn't need this feature to be honest)
4. in `MethodCallHandlerImpl.java` get rid of the frameCryptor code invocation (new obj creation and invoking methods)
5. Commit your changes to your forked repo and use it as a dependency instead of the flutter_webrtc. (Just remember that you will need to flush the flutter cache each time you commit some new changes to the repo as it won't download it right away).

If you need to fix IOS then you basically need to do the same thing but it's a bit more complicated for me as I originated from the android development and there's an objective C :)